# Lie algebra of the general linear group in terms of the ABCDE classification?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $(n\times n)$ invertible matrices.

How can its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ be written in terms of simple Lie algebras ([ABCDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group#Compact_Lie_groups)), as classified by Cartan and possibly other factors?

For example, a subgroup of the general linear group is the Lorentz group and the corresponding Lie algebra can be written as $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \simeq A_1 \times A_1 $ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R})\oplus \mathbb{R}$, which is the direct sum of an algebra of type $A_{n-1}$ and a $1$-dimensional abelian Lie algebra (which is not simple by convention).