# Application of Engel's theorem

Tags: lie-algebras

I am studying Lie Algebras and after saw Engel's theorem my professor said that
one can use Engel's theorem to compute the center of the following four Lie Algebras

$$
\mathfrak{gl}_{n}(\mathbb{F}),\mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{F}),
\mathfrak{so}_{n}(\mathbb{F}) \mbox{ and } \mathfrak{sp}_{n}(\mathbb{F})
$$

So I would like to ask if someone knows how to apply Engel's theorem in this case.
I would be happy with any solution which find the center of the last two Lie Algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Engel's theorem shows that the center of a *nilpotent* Lie algebra is always nontrivial. For the four Lie algebras we have other methods, which are better suited. Suppose that $F$ has characteristic zero. Then $\mathfrak{sl}_n(F)$ is a *simple* Lie algebra, so that its center, which is a proper ideal, has to be zero. 
For more details see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466361/center-of-mathfraksln-f).
The same is true for the other simple Lie algebras $\mathfrak{so}_n(F)$ and $\mathfrak{sp}_n(F)$. The first Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{gl}_n(F)$ is reductive, and has $1$-dimensional center isomorphic to $F$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084948/lie-algebra-of-the-general-linear-group-in-terms-of-the-abcde-classification).